# Know if a string is empty or just contains spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know I can use the following to check if a string is empty in JavaScript:

```
 if(Message != '')
```

How would I check to see if a string 'Message' in this case - is empty and doesn't contain a number of spaces. eg:

```
 '    '
```

would I need to use regular expressions?

Comment: This is Javascript not jQuery.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

jQuery doesn't replace Javascript.
You can use:

```
if (Message.replace(/\s/g, "").length > 0) {
    // Your Code
}
```

Having said that, if you really want jQuery version, try [this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/):

```
if ($.trim(Message).length > 0) {
    // Your Code
}
```

Or, so long as you're only targeting IE9+ and modern browsers, you can use the built in [trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) function.

```
if (Message.trim().length > 0) {
    // Your Code
}
```

Comment: @EugeneXa Yes, its not really needed, But I usually add it for readability (atleast for me)

Comment: works great... I really need to skill up more on javascript... jquery is the easy route... cheers... thx :)

Comment: There's an extra closing bracket I guess. Message.replace(/\s/g, "").length > 0